# 'jQuery.getJSON' not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, facebook, getjson

I am using `jQuery.getJSON` to fetch the Facebook friends list, but I am not getting it. It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but it is not working in Internet Explorer 8.

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="+aToken,
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

Also after doing a little more research I tried with this code also:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="+aToken,
    type: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
```

Comment: When you say 'not working' - do you can an error? If you use IE's Developer Tools you should see an error of some kind JavaScript or HTTP error

Comment: @beardtwizzle i didn't get any error in developer tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this to handle the error:

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + aToken, 
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
)
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); });
```

And try this hack in your code (as per comment below)

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Comment: Try this hack: Put jQuery.support.cors = true;  in your code.

Comment: @Nathan - For clarity, was the actual answer adding 'jQuery.support.cors' in the code?

Comment: I have the same error in IE8 with Jquery 1.7.2, got "access is denied" but adding jQuery.support.cors = true; doesn't help. 
Am I doing something wrong?
The code works perfectly in IE10+

Comment: @pomarc, This piece of code only shows what kind of error you are receiving, and it will help you to solve the real problem.

Answer (score 8):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support CORS in the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object which jQuery is using. Internet Explorer 8 uses [XDomainRequest object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85) which [jQuery doesn't support](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) by default.

Comment: then how to fix it is there any hack for it?

Comment: @Esailija I thought $.getJSON just did a JSONP request on a GET if it can't use CORS?

Comment: @beardtwizzle, getJSON is just `$.ajax` with `dataType: "json"`, it's not JSONP which is not ajax type of request at all. JSONP exists in jQuery.ajax though with type jsonp or with `getJSON` when the string contains `"callback=?"`. The facebook graph url as is in the op, doesn't send JSONP response anyway.

Comment: Ah yes... its the latter part that I was thinking of (i.e. when you append the callback querystring)

Comment: @beardtwizzle, yes it's the stupid overloads like that which make me rage at jQuery every day =)

Comment: Here is a plugin that adds XDomainRequest support to JQuery: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js

Answer (score 3):

I totally solved this problem using Jason Moon script, here

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/blob/master/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js

hope it helps.